# LLM for geo data annotation

Tags: geospatial, data-annotations, prompt, langchain, large-language-model

What is the best prompt and LLM to annotate and label non-structured geo data?

Example:
Label country:
{'Porto Alegre': 'Brazil',
'Castelo Branco': 'Portugal',
'Pontevedra': 'Spain',
'Brasília': 'Brazil',
'Belo Horizonte': 'Brazil',
'Mendoza': 'Argentina',
'República Dominicana': 'Dominican Republic',
'Dominican Republic': 'Dominican Republic',
'Leganés': 'Spain',
'Florida': 'United States',
'Zaragoza': 'Spain',
'CDMX': 'Mexico'}